# How to get data from another route (POST method)?

Tags: node.js

I have multiple routes setup. I want to get specific data from another route. That data is coming from a post method.

My server.js look like this:

```
var mysql = require('mysql')
var morgan = require('morgan')
var cors = require('cors')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var http = require('http')
var dateFormat = require('dateformat')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;



//middleware
var app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))

var now = new Date()




//routes
var user_details = require('./routes/users')
var user_orders = require('./routes/order')


//Use routes
app.use('/', user_details)
app.use('/', user_orders)




//Launch Server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server start at port: ' + port)
})
```

My routes/users.js :

```
var router = express.Router()
var db = require('../dbConfig')
var randomstring = require("randomstring");
var moment = require('moment')


router.post('/list', (req, res) => {
    var appendRandomString = randomstring.generate({
        length: 10,
        capitalization: 'uppercase',
        readable: true
    })
    var id = 'PEPPR_' + appendRandomString
    var email = req.body.email
    var listItems = req.body.listItems
    var listTitle = req.body.listTitle
    var date = moment().format("Do MMMM YYYY");
    var time = moment().format("LT");



    const INSERT_USER_LISTS = `INSERT INTO user_lists (id,date,time,user_email,list_title,list_items) VALUES('${id}','${date}','${time}','${email}','${listTitle}','${listItems}')`
    db.query(INSERT_USER_LISTS, (err, success) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err)
        } else {
            console.log('list added')
            res.send('list added')
        }
    })

})


module.exports = router
```

And my routes/order.js

```
var router = express.Router()
var db = require('../dbConfig')
var randomstring = require("randomstring");
var moment = require('moment')
var user_details = require('./users')

router.post('/sendOrder', (req, res) => {
    var email = req.body.email
    var status = 'Order Confirmed'
    var date = moment().format("Do MMMM YYYY");
    var time = moment().format("LT");
    var appendRandomString = randomstring.generate({
        length: 10,
        capitalization: 'uppercase',
        readable: true
    })
    var id = 'PEPPR_ORDER_' + appendRandomString
    var list_items = ''
    var list_title = ''

    var data = {
        id: id,
        email: email,
        list_items: list_items,
        list_title: list_title,
        date: date,
        time: time,
        status: status
    }

    const CREATE_ORDER = `INSERT INTO user_orders SET ?`
    db.query(CREATE_ORDER, data, (err, success) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err)
        } else {
            res.send('oc')

        }
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

I want the list_items and list_title in my order.js from users.js , this two data is coming from a POST method as you can see in users.js

Comment: I dont think you cn register multiple routes under the same path. `app.use('/', user_details)
app.use('/', user_orders)` shouldnt be like `/details and /orders`? and in the Route file you should have only a ´/´ route with multiple methods POST GET etc.

Comment: [This is a example of what I mean.](https://github.com/bradtraversy/devconnector/blob/master/server.js) Look the server.js route registration and the routes folder.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to use request body which comes to `/users` in another route `/orders`.

You are saving user data `list_title` and `list_item` in `users` table. So all you need to access the data from `/orders` route is make an additional query to db where you will select users by id\email.

Not sure which db ORM you use but in general cases your code may look like this:

```
router.post('/sendOrder', async (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;
  // declare other fields

  const user = await db.query(
    `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE '%${email}%'`,
    (err, success) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.send('ok');
      }
    }
  );

  // declare `data` object with user.list_title, user.list_item

  const CREATE_ORDER = `INSERT INTO user_orders SET ?`;
  db.query(CREATE_ORDER, data, (err, success) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.send('ok');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: in simple words, i just want list_title and list_items in the order.js But these two are in users.js

Comment: then you may try to pass them in request body or query params the same way you do it in `/list` route

Comment: or like I showed you - make an additional query to db to fetch the user by email and `user` object will have `user.list_title, user.list_item`